# Position of div on the screen

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to calculate position of a div relative to the screen.

I know position of the browser window `(window.screenX window.screenY`) and I know position of the div within window (viewport) (`div.getBoundingClientRect()`).

I know size of the entire browser window (`window.outerHeight..`) and the html window. (`window.innerHeight`)

I am trying to calculate position of the div relative to entire screen. The problem is that browser has navigation bars/toolbars and frame.

My goal is that I can pop-out a div into new browser window. The new browser window should be positioned in such way that the div within it has exactly same screen coordinates as the initial div.

[image]

Comment: Try $('classname').offset().top

Comment: Hi,
I need position relative to screen not to the browser document.

Comment: get the offset of the div minus the scrolltop of the window

Comment: I NEED IT RELATIVE TO THE MONITOR SCREEN!!!

Comment: You can do `screenY - window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight ` to get the y-position of body relative to the _screen_

Comment: Not really because browser can have extra bar at the bottom + the frame.